# concatenate the first characters of words in a string

Tags: python

Given for instance the string `"The organization for health, safety and education"`, how could I obtain:

```
Required_Output = OHSE
```

In the output,I require the string which consists of the first letters 
(upper case) of such words having length more than three.

Comment: Instead of checking the length, it might be better to use a list of [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) to decide which words not to include in the acronym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using a generator comprehension, by first using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html), and then taking the [`upper`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html) of the first character if the corresponding length of the word is `>3`:

```
s = "The organization for health, safety and education"
''.join(i[0].upper() for i in s.split() if len(i) > 3)
# 'OHSE'
```

---

Although as @tobias_k mentions, a better option might be to exclude words from your string using `stopwords`. For that you could use `nltk.corpus.stopwords`. Here's how you could do so:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
# {'but', 'wasn', 'during', 'does', 'very', 'at',...
```

And now change the above to:

```
''.join(i[0].upper() for i in s.split() if i.lower() not in stop_words)
# 'OHSE'
```

Comment: Thanks for a simple approach ! (the first answer)

Answer (score 2):

This could also be done using regular expressions (`re` module):

```
import re
txt = "The organization for health, safety and education"
letters = re.findall(r'([A-Za-z])[A-Za-z]{3,}',txt)
output = ''.join(letters).upper()
print(output) # print OHSE
```

pattern which I used grab first letter from substring consisting of 4 or more letters (1 letter is inside sole group and 3 or more outside)

Answer (score 1):

This one liner should do the trick.

```
input = 'The organization for health, safety and education'

print(''.join(map(lambda y: y[0].upper(), filter(lambda x : len(x) > 3, input.split()))))
```